# Mysql add auto increment column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add column to a table in mysql with increment numbers, no matter if some of the rows would be deleted.
For example:

```
id  name   surname  question/column
1   Peter  Peterson       1
5   Mike   Nikolson       2
11  Selena Selenson       3
```

The point is to get in every moment increment values, cause I need a list with numbers.
Hope that is no big deal for much experiences database brains.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I can think of no sensible reason for storing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add an *enumerated* column to a result set, then use variables:

```
select jb, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
from justbrackets jb cross join
      (select @rn := 0) vars
order by id;
```

Comment: I am trying to add column. If it is possible of course?